# run alias from another shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have an alias like `alias cdpy="cd python"` in my .bash_profile and I have sourced it. But I am still not able to use that in another shell script of mine, which is called pygitup.

I googled it and got some answers like adding `shopt -s expand_aliases`. I have added it to the pygitup but it still doesn't work. Am I using it wrong? This is how I use it:

```
# some code
shopt -s expand_aliases
cdpy
# some code
```

Comment: You'd have to `source` it in `pygitup.sh` as well.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks. But it only works when I call "source pygitup", which means if I just do pygitup "something", I still get command not found. Should I call source pygitup "something" every time instead of merely pygitup "something"? Is there a way to simplify the "source"?

Comment: I meant that you have to add `source ~/.bash_profile` in your `pygitup` script.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thank you! Problem resolved. Do you mind turning your comment into an answer? And I added the source ~/.bash_profile right before the shopt line. Although it works I still wonder did I add it to the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases are not inherited by external commands, so there's no alias to expand. You'd have to `source` the file that defines the alias again in your script:

```
# some code
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.bash_profile
cdpy
# some code
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run `pygitup` from your environment with a leading "dot space", it will inherit your shell's configuration, including aliases.

A simple example with a bash script:

```
user@pc:~ $ alias e='echo alias is set'
user@pc:~ $ e
alias is set
user@pc:~ $ vim pygitup.sh
user@pc:~ $ cat pygitup.sh 
#!/bin/bash
e
user@pc:~ $
user@pc:~ $ ./pygitup.sh 
./pygitup.sh: line 2: e: command not found
user@pc:~ $ 
user@pc:~ $ 
user@pc:~ $ . ./pygitup.sh       # <--- notice the leading dot
alias is set
user@pc:~ $
```

Comment: You seem to use the alias in the terminal. Does it still work if the alias is in another file?